# How to use includes/equals in the get - cypress 12

Tags: automation, cypress, selector

I have a dropdown which gets populated with card numbers, the way our front end is built the last four of the card end up in the data-cy attr for each card entry in the drop down, looking like "abc-1234"

I know I can isolate the last four number of the card number variable into it's own variable with something like:

```
var cardNumberShort = cardNumber.slice((cardNumber.length - 4),(cardNumber.length))
```

My question is can I build a selector for the cards in the dropdown which uses the cardNumberShort to target the card I'm looking for? I assume there's a way make a selector use an includes or equals to do so?

I've tried using includes or equals in the get, but no luck so far

Answer (score 2):

When selecting by attribute, you can use a number of partial selection methods given here [Category: Attribute](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).

I would say you are looking for **Attribute Ends With Selector [name$=”value”]**

```js
const cardNumberShort = cardNumber.slice(-4)
cy.get(`[data-cy$="${cardNumberShort}"]`)
```

using string template to inject your short number into the selector.

Not sure what the `abc` part represents, but you could add it into the template

```js
const cardNumberShort = cardNumber.slice(-4)
cy.get(`[data-cy$="abc-${cardNumberShort}"]`)
```

Ref also [MDN string slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but is used the dropdowns like this :

```
   cy.get(dropDown).click()
   cy.get(dropDownList).contains('text').click()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).